# Where is the line between Python and GIS?

Tags: discussion, scope, stack-overflow

Related to [When are field calculator scripting questions on topic?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3796/when-are-field-calculator-scripting-questions-on-topic) and various comments on that Meta question (and many Main questions since) I think it is clear that we do not have consensus on where the line should be drawn between pure Python (better researched/asked at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)) and Python functionality that is core to modern GIS (on-topic for here).

Where would you draw that line?

Answer (score 13):

Another excellent example of why defining the line for 'pure' Python questions is going to be difficult: [Using variable in SelectByAttribute_management](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170587/using-variable-in-selectbyattribute-management).

At the lowest level possible, it is purely a Python syntax issue.

However, the error given would indicate an error outside of Python, within the ArcGIS API:

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 1, in    File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6435, in
>   SelectLayerByAttribute     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid
>   expression Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).

If you look up this error message you'll [find](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00vp00000026000358.htm):

> The SQL expression is invalid.

It takes knowledge of both ArcGIS and Python to understand what the problem is and what the solution should be.

Now, the question is, should I answer this? It's actually fairly simple, and I've already spent more time creating this answer than it would have taken to do that.
I could also vote to close it as off-topic. But, given the fact that I've already taken the time to read and understand the question, and I *know* a solution, am I really improving this community by voting to close this question?

At the very least, I believe trying to define what is 'pure' Python is going to be a moving target, and something this community will struggle with on an on-going basis.