# Using GIS SE rather than Stack Overflow for Here Maps questions?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed

I'm programming for living and StackOverflow is a life savior for all kinds of issues. Sometimes, when I dig deeper into a very specific aspect (such as geometries or design), it's actually better to go for *math.stackexchange* or *ux.stackexchange*. I stress: **sometimes**.

The response **should** be more extensive there but due to specificness of the question in combination with a lower number of users, it's not.

My situation is like this. I've started to poke around with maps (on a very playful level) so I'm an expert beginner (10 years dev vs 10 days GIS, hehe) and due to different circumstances, I'll go with Here Maps only.

The question is if it's appropriate to ask Here-specific question (on, perhaps, very basic level) on this site or if it's recommended to stick to SO.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think Here Maps is more on-topic here at GIS SE than it would be at Stack Overflow.

We have currently not had all that many questions tagged [here-maps](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/here-maps) and would welcome more.

As on any site, be sure to:

- take our 2-minute [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour);
- review the [first (on topic) page of the help](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- review a few recent Q&As to get a feel for what potential answerers are looking for in questions asked here.
- [NOT cross-post](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4068/115) between Stack Overflow and here:

Comment: I'll assume that the contents of that link are more or less equivalent to the other Stack Exchange sites but just to make sure, I'll take a look. It would be nice to cross-post the questions, like in the good old days of usenet...

Comment: @KonradViltersten The Tours and first pages of the [help/on-topic] are not all the same so I recommend reviewing both.  Also, please do not cross-post between [so] and here: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/4068/115

Answer (score -1):

#### It depends.

Programming question related to accessing Here's APIs? **Probably StackOverflow**
Question related to geography, cartography of Here Maps? **Likely GIS.SE**

I agree that questions related to Here Maps are on-topic here, but would remind you of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You may find that asking a technical programming question related to Here's many APIs will have more odds of finding a useful answer on Stack Overflow. This is not because there are more people using Here's products on SO, but because there are more developers working with APIs who might have encountered a similar problem.

Comment: I think the GIS developers here at GIS SE have a lot more to offer than just geography and cartography answers. IT developer questions should be asked at [so] but I think GIS developer questions about spatial libraries and APIs are much more on-topic here.

Comment: Most definitely. I have spent much of the last week pulling data from the Here and TomTom APIs. Programming skills are increasing likely to be found in GIS professionals, and I think programming questions relating mapping APIs are very much on topic.