# Clearly off-topic question reopened?

Tags: discussion, scope

I voted to close [Running script over every file in folder using GDAL in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/218338/2856) as off topic and it was put on hold.

It is a pure python question and has no GIS component.  The question mentions GDAL, but that is irrelevant as it is just asking about looping over files and doing something with them. The question could be asked as "how do I open and read every .txt file file in a directory" and it would get the same answer (use glob or os.walk)

It seems to have been reopened.

Any reason why?

Answer (score 7):

I voted to close that question ([Running script over every file in folder using GDAL in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218338)) too, and for the same reason that you cite.  It's [only answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/218341/115) seems to reinforce the point you make about it being a pure Python question because no mention of GDAL or any other spatial Python library was needed to answer it.

The question was later flagged with this text attached:

> I feel this was wrongly put on hold. The question is clear and
>   concise, contains a question involving remote sensing and python, and
>   from I've read on what's appropriate for this site it seems to fit the
>   bill.

and the processing of that flag has led to it being re-opened.

Personally, I would have dismissed the flag with a comment like:

> The question is clear and concise.  It mentions GDAL, and has been
>   asked by someone doing remote sensing, but the question distills to
>   "How to process every file in a folder using Python?" and as such is
>   better researched at Stack Overflow.  If you need to ask a question there be 
>   sure to trim the GIS-specific aspects from it because you will be 
>   addressing IT rather than GIS specialists.

In retrospect, as a moderator, before I voted to close, I think it would have been better for me to have made a comment (like that above) so that the asker had more information about why I was voting to close.

This is an example of our community being unsure as to  [Where is the line between Python and GIS?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4058)